# jQuery and MVC3 Razor producing strange URL on Android browsers

Tags: android, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I'm working on an MVC3 (with Razor) / jQuery Mobile application and am having trouble navigating back on many areas of my application when using an Android browser (or user agent).

The problem appears to be in the URL that gets created with the @Url.Action method. On iPhones and PC browsers the URL looks like this:

```
<li class="cl"><a href="/CustomerLookup/Search?ep=Home&amp;t=8cf20faa37155b8"><span>Customer Lookup</span></a></li>
```

but on Android browsers or in Chrome using the Android user agent the URL looks like this:

```
<li class="cl"><a href="/(F(Kdqb5nTlCaTP52GkHZ76P50MXAvnUCexKHt0ucPisYJ0iubQ3jwKk6-tiqxAtGVdBmiOgq4mW1-ZF3XUZJc5Y9BHnXVa2fWeIyFE5BxUwmZRhPjbm4L8AWDeymlpAcYJ9ABEPfu5i5_JmvAFinX8y9Jnwj0YeQRnpx_NCVjGqEcuFB-0g5NYcOI_WAsixNP90))/CustomerLookup/Search?ep=Home&amp;t=8cf20fb0b1db618"><span>Customer Lookup</span></a></li>
```

When I click this link I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: data-url='/(F(Kdqb5nTlCaTP52GkHZ76P50MXAvnUCexKHt0ucPisYJ0iubQ3jwKk6-tiqxAtGVdBmiOgq4mW1-ZF3XUZJc5Y9BHnXVa2fWeIyFE5BxUwmZRhPjbm4L8AWDeymlpAcYJ9ABEPfu5i5_JmvAFinX8y9Jnwj0YeQRnpx_NCVjGqEcuFB-0g5NYcOI_WAsixNP90])/CustomerLookup/Search?ep=Home&t=8cf20fb0b1db618')
```

I'm now unable to navigate back to the original page.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks alike you have cookies disabled on your android and session is being thrown into your url.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but cookies are enabled in the Chrome browser and it's only my site I'm having trouble with on the Android phone. It's interesting that using Chrome set to the iPhone user agent works correctly but the Android user agent doesn't. I'm wondering if jQuery Mobile is adding something...

Comment: It was cookies that was causing the problem. I enabled them the forms setting in MVC3 and that's fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have cookies disabled on your android and session is being thrown into your url.

Comment: This answer was close. The MVC application wasn't setting the cookie state correctly. The clients were enabled to use cookies but the web site wasn't. I'm marking this as the accepted answer (and Thanks!).